# Python 3.3 - Tkinter object access inside functions

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.3

I'm trying to build a GUI for a simple application with Tkinter on Python 3.3.0.
I have stumbled upon a little programming quirk that at first sight it seems wrong. Although it isn't a problem *per se* (it isn't affecting my objective) it doesn't make sense in a Pythonic way.

So, here is the source:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def foo():
    def bar():
        root.destroy()
    root = Tk()
    mainframe = ttk.Frame(root).grid(column=0, row=0)
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text="Goodbye",command=bar).grid(column=1, row=1)
    root.mainloop()

foo()
```

Running this and clicking the `"Goodbye"` button closes the window, as expected... however here resides the problem. If I run this simplified version of the code:

```
def foo():
    def bar():
        hee = "spam"
    hee = "eggs"
    print(hee)
    bar()
    print(hee)

foo()

>>> eggs
>>> eggs
```

I don't access the `hee` defined in `foo()` and create a new `hee` in `bar()`, as it should. If I were now to add `nonlocal hee` to the beginning of the `bar()` def, the output:

```
>>> eggs
>>> spam
```

Would be the expected one.

So, my question here is why I am able to call the `root` object in the first example without first declaring it nonlocal?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Short Description of Python Scoping Rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules)

Comment: @Eric Thanks. After reading it, I understood the problem. Since in the simplified code I explicitly **declared** a variable, where in the real example I accessed an attribute from a previously declared object, thus I was following the LEGB scope rule. Assuming I didn't declare another root object at `bar()` it should scope down to the one declared on `foo()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As according to [Short Description of Python Scoping Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules) (see also [The Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)) object name scope resolution goes according to the LEGB rule (Local, Enclosing functions, Globals, Built-ins).

That being said, the following example exemplifies the rule:

```
class ni:
    bar = "hello"

def foo():
    pi = ni()
    def bar():
        pi.bar = "eggs"
    pi.bar = "spam"
    print(pi.bar)
    bar()
    print(pi.bar)

ni.bar

>>> hello

foo()

>>> spam
>>> eggs
```

The main difference between this and the simplified version of the code is the explicit assignment of a variable named `hee`. Here the `pi.bar` in `bar()` looks for the `pi` object first in `bar()`. Not finding it, it begins to scope down to `foo()`, where the `pi` object is first declared.